# Display phpmyadmin "Export templates" section

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin no longer displays the export templates section after an update

[image]

Do you know how to display this section?

Current phpmyadmin version
`4.9.5deb2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create the phpmyadmin database in order to have the export templates section displayed
I imported it from this demo
https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/export&db=phpmyadmin&server=1